# Deleting numpy subarray based off of first element in subarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` array being generated from a function as follows

```
 circles = [[ 56, 152, 26],
 [288, 300, 25],
 [288, 362,  25],
 [288, 238,  24],
 [318, 298,  45],
 [220, 366, 29]]
```

I want to check if all the values in the first element of each subarray are consistent (mathematically close, not differing by a large amount i.e. > 5) and remove the subarrays that don't conform to this condition.
So in this case, i want to remove any subarray that is greater than `288 + 5` or less than `288 - 5`. Any thoughts?

Comment: what's your desired output in this case?

Comment: `[[288, 300,  25],
   [288, 362,  25],
   [288, 238,  24]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution using `mode`:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import mode
>>> eps = 5
>>> most_freq = mode(circles[:, 0])[0][0]
>>> mask = np.abs(circles[:, 0] - most_freq) <= eps
>>> circles[mask]
array([[288, 300,  25],
   [288, 362,  25],
   [288, 238,  24]])
```

**Edit:**
if your `circles` array is limited to to non-negative integers, you can use the following expression for `most_freq`:

```
most_freq = np.bincount(circles[:, 0]).argmax()
```

Comment: When i try that it gives me this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: @HarshVedant, Looks, your `circles` is a list if lists. Try `circles = np.array(circles)` before processing it.

Comment: Never mind, i was messing around in the python terminal and not my actual code, where it wasn't a numpy array. This is brilliant, thanks!